# Is The Powershell Active Directory Module Encrypted?

Tags: powershell, encryption

Simple question:

From a machine that is not the AD Server, if I call:

```
Set-ADAccountPassword 'CN=Jeremy Los,OU=Accounts,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com' -Reset -NewPassword 
    (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "p@ssw0rd" -Force)
```

Is that encrypted on the network or can the password be sniffed?

Comment: I would be surprised if it sent the password in clear text over the network. Under the hood, the cmdlet probably uses the [NetUserSetInfo function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370659.aspx). This function relies on the RPC mechanism to encrypt at the redirector level (depending on the security levels that both systems support).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to give brief about this, I can tell you that effectively happening here is that PowerShell is using the native **Windows Data Protection API** (DAPI) functionality to encrypt the password from the 'secure string' into a text string.

This string can be written to a plain text file, but the way that DAPI works is that the encryption is such that only the original user on the original machine the encryption was performed on can decrypt the string back into a ‘Secure string’ to be reused.

It is one of the pretty effective ways to send the password over the network.

Refer the [Windows Data Protection API Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) to understand in a better way.

Comment: One thing should be noted that the password can be key-logged on the initiating PC if set like this, or probably captured in a screenshot. I also think that RPC connections in local network involve some encryption, but this is not certain. Anyway a `SecureString` is a decently good way to send/store passwords.

Comment: @Vesper:  Yup. Even I do believe so